# How to grant full admin access to another member of an AWS organization?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I've set up an AWS organization of which I am the 'master'. When I go to the organizations home page (https://console.aws.amazon.com/organizations/home), I see all the other members.

However, when another user goes to that page, he only sees his account belongs to that organization.

I would like to make it so that the other user has all the permissions that the 'master' account does so that he effectively sees the same console.

It seems like the guide relevant to that is "Granting Full Admin Permissions to a User" at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_permissions_iam-policies.html. However, the guide only explains how to create the policy, not how to assign it to a user.

If I go to the 'Users' page, I only see one user, 'lucy-s3-user', which is a member of the 'lucy-engineering' group:

[image]

The 'lucy-engineering' group has a bunch of extensive permissions:

[image]

However, if I try to add users to the group, I don't see any users show up in the drop-down menu:

[image]

Shouldn't I see the members of the organization here? How can I grant full AWS access to other members of the organization?

Comment: I would recommend you to post redacted screenshots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All accounts (master or member) you have in your AWS Organizations are separate accounts and is different than IAM users. IAM users are account specific e.g. you could have an IAM user named Bob in your master account and member accounts but they are completely separate entities.

Now, when you (could be Root like you are doing now or IAM user) log in to your Master account, you can only view and access resources which belongs to the Master account. Similarly when someone (again root or IAM user) logs in to any of the member account, they can see resources which are owned by the member account. Consider the Organization as a container of accounts which can be managed by master and gives you consolidated billing and other features like SCP (Service Control Policy).

It is expected that you'd not see member accounts in IAM user or dropdown because the accounts are not IAM users. If you want member accounts should be able to access resources in master account, you have to do cross-account IAM role as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_create_for-user.html) (assume role can be done by IAM user/role and will NOT work when you are signed in as Root user).

Also, will request to edit the screenshots to remove email and AWS account ids :)